# SSIS Connection to source

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an issue while executing an ssis package.

I am able to connect to the source using SSMS (the source is SQL SERVER 11.0), and run SQL select statement.

But when i'm using my SSIS package with the same user, i'm getting an issue :

0x80004005 : Login failed for user 'XXX'

On the source, my user is listed in the database users as db_datareader.

So, what are the good rights to let SSIS retrieve the data.

Thanks,

Comment: If you are using a SQL (not windows) user, and you can connect ok in SSMS, then your package is not doing what you think it is. It should be able to connect fine. Does this error appear in BIDS when you're running your package interactively? You need to supply a lot more information.

Comment: I'm not using a SQL user, i use a windows user define on Active Directory, and i connect to SSMS using windows auth. The error message appears when i launch my package using SSIS (visual studio), and when i want to do a preview on my datasource.

Comment: Based on the info provided I can't help any further. The package is just doing what you would do in SSMS... running a select statement.

Comment: I think SSIS needs more rights on the database to access the data, while a simple select on ssms needs less rights. Wich infos do you need ? i will try to provide these ones

Comment: better to restart your sql machine and take new connection sometimes this package will give such type of authentication problems...